# How to resolve Argument of type '"" | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean' in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

In Angular-14, I am implementing server-side search filter and pagination. I have this code:

From the web api end point, startDate and endDate come as Date (for example, 2023-12-23).

The startDate and endDate can allow nullable

```
public class PagingDto
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }

}

public class TransactionFilter : PagingDto
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-60);
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
}
```

**ANGULAR:**

**interface:**

```
export interface IPageItem {
  applicatantName: string;
  reliefName: string;
  description: string;
  posted: string;
  postingDate: Date;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}

export interface IData {
  pageItems: IPageItem[];
  currentPage: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalRecord: number;
}

export interface ILeaveList {
  data: IData;
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}
```

**service:**

```
import { ILeaveList } from 'src/app/leave-list.model';

getAllLeave(startDate?: Date,endDate?: Date,searchQuery?:string, pageNumber?: number,pageSize?: number): Observable<ILeaveList[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams()
  .set('StartDate', startDate ?? '')
  .set('EndDate', endDate ?? '')
  .set('searchQuery', searchQuery?.toString() ?? '')
  .set('pageNumber', pageNumber?.toString() ?? '')
  .set('pageSize', pageSize?.toString() ?? '');
  return this.http.get<ILeaveList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/leaves/all-leaves', { params: params });
}
```

I got this error:

Argument of type '"" | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean'.
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.ts(2345)

Then

```
startDate ?? '' and endDate ?? ''  are highlighted.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `startDate.toString()`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - I don't want to convert it to string because I want to get it in component as date. Any other choice?

Comment: @Gbenga: Try to use unary `+`:   `.set('StartDate', new Date(+startDate) ?? '')`

Comment: @Jackdaw - Same error still occurred

Comment: AFAIK the key-pair value for params requires the value to be string, number or boolean type. You should convert the date as an ISO string with `startDate.toISOString()`. When the API side receive the request, it will automatically deserialize as `DateTime` type.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you have the Evernote extension enabled in Google Chrome.

If you need this extension you chose choose to enable it on click in the extnsion settings.